# Bulk deletion of activities

Tags: sapb1

We need to delete hundreds of business partners from our DB. We can't do this because they have activities associated with them. So, is there a way of bulk-deleting activities? DTW won't work - it only allows adding data or modifying existing data.

Comment: which system are you talking about? SAP ERP, BusinessOne, CRM?

Comment: It's SAP Business One, version 9.1

Comment: Can activities be deleted? I can't remember off the top of my head. If they can, then I have two suggestions: 1) Boyum's B1 Usability Package may have a tool to delete activities in the Master Data Manager, but I'm not positive. 2) You could consider opening a ticket with SAP. Occasionally, they're willing to provide update queries for things like that (but not often).

Comment: Will the Data Archive Wizard do that? Failing that, you might have to spin some custom SAP-DI code.